# Dual Booting Windows7(ulimate 32-bit) and ubuntu 13.04

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows 7 (ultimate 32-bit) installed and i have downloaded  ubuntu 13.04 .iso file how do i continue do i need to make a partition,then how to?i don't know anything.please help me thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well the above comment, and answer will get you going.  But before doing that, you need to make either a bootable DVD or a USB flash drive.  Since you're on Windows now, you can burn a DVD by using [ImgeBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).  Its a free application that will allow you to make a bootable DVD from the ISO.  Or if you prefer, you can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make a bootable USB flash.

Once you do either of those, make sure you set your BIOS to boot from either the DVD or the USB flash, and then follow the instruction from mentioned in the answer, and comment.